# Align nav-bar to the right using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend, navbar

I'm trying to align the navbar components to the right. The code is given below. I tried with
`ml-auto` but it's not giving the desired result. The result that I'm getting is attached below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="bg-info">
  <div class="row text-white">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-9 p-3 pl-5">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-3 my-auto ml-auto">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <!-- me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 -->
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active text-white" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Know More</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Actions</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Result
[image: Current result]
I want the home, know more, etc.. content to be right-aligned. I have divided it initially into two columns. Then gave the second one the `ml-auto` class. What's the issue here?

Comment: I've converted your code to a functional snippet. As you can see (in the full page demo) it works as you desire. Apparently there's more to the situation than what you've shown.

Comment: @Pieterjan, that's incorrect. Rarely would that be the case. Also, floats are an old technique and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I checked safari, chrome, firefox and the snippet checker in StackOverflow.

**All are showing the correct styling** and not what you screenshot-ed. Maybe you have an extension that is injecting some sort of custom CSS? Or you don't have the bootstrap file loaded properly?

Your font also seems a bit off in the screenshot.

What my Chrome looks like :

[image]

Comment: Welcome. You shouldn't post answers to unanswerable questions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Could be very easy. Remove all `ml-auto`'s then use `d-flex` to `justify-content-end` (right). `justify-content-start` would be the left. But.... As somebody else pointed out. When I try your code - Your menu is on the right hand side and Header on the left as required.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light d-flex justify-content-end">
```